# Consigo usar o activerecord para consultas basicas? Sem mapeamento?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record, automatização

Eu faço testes automatizados de um sistema grande, preciso validar muitas tabelas em bancos de dados diferentes. Estou pensando em usar o Active Record, mas todos os exemplos que vi em pesquisas mostram que as tabelas a serem usadas são mapeadas primeiro e usadas como modelo. Existe alguma maneira de usar o Active Record sem mapeamento em alguns casos? Se sim, quais são?
Eu estou usando atualmente OCI8 atualmente

Se para uma simples validação disso eu mapear cada tabela será muito demorada, os ganhos são realmente tão altos?

Comment: Dá pra fazer no AR, mas não é bem pra isso q ele é feito. Pro seu caso, eu usaria Sequel ( http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer isso é utilizando o método execute, veja o exemplo:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

result = conn.execute "SELECT id, email, age FROM users LIMIT 3"
```

O resultado será um objeto Mysql::Result, pode-se iterar dessa forma:

```
Rubyresult = conn.execute "SELECT id, email, age FROM users LIMIT 2" result.each do |user|   puts "id: %s" % user[0]   puts "email: %s" %  user[1]   puts "age: %s" % user[2] puts end
```

Atenção, tome os cuidados necessários para não sofrer um ataque através de SQL Injection, pode começar a evitar utilizando o método quote:

```
Rubyquery = "SELECT id, email, age FROM users WHERE email = %s" % conn.quote("' OR 1=1 #") puts query
# => SELECT id, email FROM users WHERE email = '\' OR 1=1 #'
```

Voce pode utilizar outros métodos como o método select_all. Este método retorna um array de hashes, com o nome das colunas como índice, tornando mais simples a iteração.

```
Rubyresult = conn.select_all "SELECT id, email FROM users LIMIT 2"
result.each do |user|
  puts "id: %s" % user['id']
  puts "email: %s" % user['email']
  puts
end
```

Para os casos em que tudo o que você precisa é de apenas uma linha como resultado, você pode utilizar o método select_one:

```
Rubyresult = conn.select_one("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM users")
puts result['total']
```

No Rails, todos os modelos estendem a classe ActiveRecord::Base. Por isso, os métodos acima também estão disponíveis no modelo.

```
Rubyclass User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.all
    connection.select_all "SELECT id, email FROM users"
  end
end

puts User.all
# => [{"id"=>"1", "email"=>"user@example.com"}, {"id"=>"2", "email"=>"another@example.com
```

Comment: Ahhhh, muito obrigada!! De verdade, era isso que estava tentando entender se era possivel fazer!